# Getting a results rank in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that is getting submission entries from my database along with how much each entry has raised. I am trying to get the "Rank" of the submission based on the amount raised vs all other submissions.

The second return should be Rank 1 because it has a higher totalRaised amount than the first record which should be rank 2. Am I close??

My sp:

```
 SELECT A.[id],
             A.[petName],
             A.[petCaption],
             B.[petType],
             C.[FirstName] as ownerFirstName,
             C.[LastName] as ownerLastName,
             D.[imageName],

             (
                SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),sum(transactionAmount), 1) as totalRaised,
                RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum(transactionAmount) DESC) AS Rank
                FROM petContestTransactions
                WHERE submissionID = A.[id] and paymentType = 'donation'
                FOR    XML PATH ('transactionDetails'), TYPE, ELEMENTS
             )
      FROM petContestSubmissions as A
      JOIN petContestTypes as B
      ON A.[petType] = B.[id]
      JOIN EmpTable as C
      ON A.[empID] = C.EmpID
      JOIN petContestImages as D
      ON A.[image] = D.[submissionID]
      JOIN petContestTransactions as E
      ON E.[submissionID] = A.[id]
      WHERE E.[transactionStatus] = 'completed' and E.[paymentType] = 'submission' 
      FOR    XML PATH ('submission'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

XML Returned:

```
<root>
  <submission>
    <id>1</id>
    <petName>Nala</petName>
    <petCaption>Shes a wonder pup!</petCaption>
    <petType>Dog</petType>
    <ownerFirstName>Carl</ownerFirstName>
    <ownerLastName>H</ownerLastName>
    <imageName>nalaHUS123.png</imageName>
    <transactionDetails>
      <totalRaised>130.00</totalRaised>
      <Rank>1</Rank>
    </transactionDetails>
  </submission>
  <submission>
    <id>2</id>
    <petName>Simba</petName>
    <petCaption>Shes a wonder pup!</petCaption>
    <petType>Cat</petType>
    <ownerFirstName>Carl</ownerFirstName>
    <ownerLastName>H</ownerLastName>
    <imageName>simbaHUS123.png</imageName>
    <transactionDetails>
      <totalRaised>250.00</totalRaised>
      <Rank>1</Rank>
    </transactionDetails>
  </submission>
</root>
```

Comment: What entity are you trying to rank the total raised against? All employees, all other submissions?

Comment: The `totailRaised` amount - rank it by the most money earned

Comment: I think you should rank with a partition by petContestTransactions.Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.[id],
    A.[petName],
    A.[petCaption],
    B.[petType],
    C.[FirstName] as ownerFirstName,
    C.[LastName] as ownerLastName,
    D.[imageName],
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY sum(F.totalRaised) DESC) AS Rank
FROM petContestSubmissions as A
JOIN petContestTypes as B
ON A.[petType] = B.[id]
JOIN EmpTable as C
ON A.[empID] = C.EmpID
JOIN petContestImages as D
ON A.[image] = D.[submissionID]
JOIN petContestTransactions as E
ON E.[submissionID] = A.[id]
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT sum(transactionAmount) as totalRaised,
    FROM petContestTransactions pt
    WHERE pt.submissionID = A.[id] and pt.paymentType = 'donation'
) F
WHERE E.[transactionStatus] = 'completed' and E.[paymentType] = 'submission' 
FOR    XML PATH ('submission'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

I use outer apply to get the totalRaised and then you can rank it directly.